# Load data infile, difference between Windows and Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, csv, load

I've a file which I need to import to MySQL table. Here's my command

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\test.csv'
INTO TABLE logs
fields terminated by '|'
LINES terminated BY '\n'
```

This looks fine in Windows, but in Linux it inserts only the first row and generates an error in log file

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/myuser/test.csv'
INTO TABLE logs
fields terminated by '|'
LINES terminated BY '\n'
```

What I need to change in Linux?

Comment: Looks like there is an issue with the linebreaks. Maybe some editor or something converted the MS-Windows style linebreaks to normal unix style linebreaks when you transferred the file? Check with a hexeditor to be sure.

Comment: Would you post hex dump of fragment starting at 2 characters before end of third string and ending 2 characters of third string?

Comment: Personally, I find this one of the most frustrating things about `LOAD DATA INFILE` that it can't cope with variable line endings. I have to import CSV data from several sources and `LOAD DATA INFILE` ought to be perfect for it, but it fails because the different sources use different line-breaks. Grrr.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested this "LOAD DATA INFILE" in windows 8.1 using mysql 5.6.17. Below is the table format

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+ 
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| charactor | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| movie     | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/kaviranga/Desktop/scifi.csv' INTO TABLE scifi FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 0 LINES (charactor,movie);
```

This worked perfectly and the csv file format I've used as below

```
"Soldier 2","Pirates of the Carribian 2"
"Soldier 1","Pirates of the Carribian 4"
```

Don't use like below.It may causes errors.

```
'C:\Users\kaviranga\Desktop\scifi.csv'
```

I've included this answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`LINES terminated by '\r\n'`

in Linux machine.