# Trying to load text file in mysql but error is no such file or directory

Tags: mysql

I am trying to load (a.txt) file into mysql with the load command, but it says `no such file or directory` even if file is present at the specified path?

```
load data local infile  'F:\makarand\a.txt' 
 into TABLE file;

load data local infile  'F:\makarand\a.txt' 
 into TABLE file;
```

I have tried this also tried by removing local word but the issue remains same

It says:

```
Error No 2:No such file or directory
```

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: `file` is a protected name in mysql... either do quotes arround it, or rename the table file to something else. It now tries to search for a file, rather than the table.

Answer (score 0):

`File` is a protected name in MYSQL

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

It expects a filename now, rather than your suggested table. Either rename the table (use a pre- or suffix) or try to quote it in your query. These kind of things sadly happen, thus I always use a prefix on my tables, to make sure i dont encounter this kind of things.

// edit //

See also this topic. This has nothing to do with Windows or Linux

[Load data infile, difference between Windows and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979273/load-data-infile-difference-between-windows-and-linux)

Comment: i am using windows operating system .Will you please give ans example with query for loading file

Comment: Add a prefix to your table file, like `mak_file` then simply run your statement `load data local infile  'F:\makarand\a.txt' into TABLE mak_file;` The term file in your query is simply a protected name and cant be named like that. It has NOTHING to do with your operation system. Check your query in something like phpmyadmin.